# Why macroTransform not triggered?

Tags: scala, macros

I write some code to test this function, to learn how to do the annotation macro, but the method not invoked.

```
class column extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro impl
}

def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = ???

@column class c {}
```

I also add breakpoint in the impl, but not suspended; I add some log in the impl body, but nothing logged.

It seems this method even not invoked.

Why? Did I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The most typical reason for this is missing the reference to the macro paradise compiler plugin. If macro paradise is not enabled for your project (in sbt or in the IDE), then macro annotations won't expand.